# How to use split function on object data in react

Tags: react-native

I am getting data in below eg format and I want to use split function on 'testabc1223./67767' but I can't use it as it is an object and split cannot be used on object please let me know how can I use split on this

```
{
   name: 'testabc1223./67767'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shuld get the object property like that:

```
YOUR_OBJECT.name.split(...);
```